# When an ICMP error message contains error, how it is checked and why isn't an ICMP message generated?

Tags: networking, icmp

Since no ICMP error message is generated in response to an ICMP error message, how are the errors in errorneous ICMP messages detected, or is the message discarded?

Comment: If you send to a connected UDP socket and the target UDP port isn't open, the sending application will get an ICMP UNREACHABLE error. So the premiss of your question is false.

Answer (score 0):

If error messages were generated in response to error messages, you could end up with a loop. It's more important to ensure loops and traffic storms aren't created, so bad ICMP messages are just ignored.